# how to encrypt passwords so that it cannot be easily cracked?

Tags: php, encryption, passwords

I have used `md5()` for this purpose

```
// username and password sent from form 

$username=$_POST['myusername']; 
$password=$_POST['mypassword']; 
$encrypted_password=md5($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$encrypted_password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

But I heard that it is not safe.
I'm a beginner so please suggest me a good password encryting method? also if post data was intercepted would it be visible as plaintext?

Comment: Use PHP's [password_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) functions

Comment: What about letting mysql handle the encryption?
In general you can say that complex passwords are harder to crack, so try to set a policy that enforces strong passwords.

Comment: If your not using HTTPS then yes the password is sent from the client in the clear.

Comment: Password hashing isn't your only problem. You also have an SQL injection problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm a beginner so please suggest me a good password encryting method

Make use of [`crypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) instead of `md5()`

```
<?php
$hashed_password = crypt('mypassword'); // let the salt be automatically generated
if (crypt($user_input, $hashed_password) == $hashed_password) {
   echo "Password verified!";
}
?>
```

Some examples from the [`PHP Manual`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php#refsect1-function.crypt-examples)

> also if post data was intercepted would it be visible as plaintext ?

Ofcourse! If you are really concerned about that, Get an **`SSL`** Certificate configured on your domain.

Comment: dont knw much about ssl certificate....let me google it...anyway thanx for your effort

Comment: Warning: The usage of `crypt()` in this form, will generate an unsalted DES hash, which is very unsecure for hashing passwords!

Comment: Good Point.But that is far more secure than `md5()`.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.5 you could use the new `password_hash`

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

in older versions, there's a compatibility layer which do the same: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat